# Finding the set of all points where a function is differentiable

Tags: derivatives

Let $$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{sin|x^2 - 5x + 6|}{x^2 - 5x + 6},  & \text{if x $\ne$ 2,3} \\
1,  & \text{if x = 2 or 3}
\end{cases}$$

I want to find all the points where f is differentiable. Clearly, I need to check only at the points 2 and 3. I tried differentiating the first part, but couldn't solve.

Please Help.

Comment: Can't go wrong with the definition of the derivative!

Comment: In the definition we have absolute value, right? Is it $\sin(x^2-5x+6)$ or $\sin|x^2-5x+6|$

Comment: Absolute value is still there. However, as an example, you know that when $x ≈ 3$, $|x^2 - 5x + 6| = -(x^2 - 5x + 6)$